# MVVMCross - Button inside ListItem

Tags: mvvmcross

I have created a List with a Model class called User. The List Item contains a button, and I would like to trigger a command on the viewmodel containing the list, instead of the button. Is it possible to set ItemsSource to an ObservableCollection, but set the DataContext of the List to the ViewModel containing the ObservableCollection.

I have a ViewModel which contains an ObservaleCollection:

FindFriendsViewModel:

```
    private ObservableCollection<User> _SearchResult = new ObservableCollection<User>();

    public ObservableCollection<User> SearchResult
    {
        get
        {
            return _SearchResult;
        }
        set
        {
            _SearchResult = value;
        }
    }
```

And a View which shows the List, FindFriendsView:

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/LoginActivity_LoginFormContainer"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip">
                <MvxListView
                    android:id="@+id/FindFriendsView_SearchResult"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
                    android:background="@color/transparent"
                    android:cacheColorHint="@color/transparent"
                    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/listitem_user"
                    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource SearchResult" />
            </LinearLayout>
```

The ListItem:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageview"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            local:MvxBind="Text FirstName"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            local:MvxBind="Text LastName"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/darkgrey"
        local:MvxBind="Text Email" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ListItemUser_BtnFollow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/GreyButton"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_user_red"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:text="@string/listitem_user_follow"
        local:MvxBind="Click FollowCommand; Visibility IsFriend, Converter=Visibility"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/ListItemUser_BtnFollowing"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/RedButton"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_tick"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="@string/listitem_user_following"
        local:MvxBind="Visibility IsFriend, Converter=InvertedVisibility"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

The ListItem contains two buttons, where only one of them is visible at a time, and only one of them contains a Click Command. I would love to be able to get the Button to trigger a command on the FindFriendsViewModel, instead of the Model Class User.

Comment: Sorry - but I don't understand your question. Perhaps it might help if you include more detail - e.g. some sample code for your ViewModel, ObservableCollection and UI

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize weak references (or WeakSubscribe as it's implemented in MvvmCross) to implement the functionality that you want. In your view model, you can subscribe to INotifyPropertyChanged of your models that you bind to the list. Once you get a notification that a button fired an ICommand, your ViewModel can respond accordingly.

Here's a little example

```
using Cirrious.CrossCore.WeakSubscription;

foreach (var sale in Sales)
{                
    var token = sale.WeakSubscribe(sale_PropertyChanged);
}

void sale_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Accepted")
    {
        CalculateSalesTotals();
    }
}
```

Comment: But wouldn't this solution require the Model Class containing an ICommand?

Comment: Yes, it will require a model containing an ICommand. You may be better off creating a view model for User.

Answer (score 0):

Better try to use [swipelistview](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview). I will do it, hopefully it will be possible to wrap this lib. Currently i solved my problem (button inside listitem) with longpresss <-> context menu.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you need to fire commands from a listitem, you will need to use a viewmodel wrapper around your listitem class. The wrapper will implement the command, and then axml will then bind to the command in the wrapper. If you want the command to execute in the list viewmodel, then you can pass an action to the wrapper, and execute the action in the viewmodel.